# Using OpenCV to take a particular amount of images without pressing any key

Tags: python, opencv

I wish to write a program for face recognition. I want my program to automatically take a specific number of images(say,5). Here is what I am currently doing:

```
import cv2

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
a=0
count=0
for a in range(5):
    ret,img=cam.read()

    cv2.imshow("Test",img)

    if not ret:
        break

    k=cv2.waitKey(1)
 
    print("Image"+str(count)+"saved")
    file='C:/Users/User/Desktop/FACEREC/known_faces/img_test/ad2'+str(count)+'.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(file,img)
    a+=1 

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

           

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It shows "Image 0 saved" five times but in the folder(ad2), there is only a single image. Need some guidance.

Thank you

Comment: You increment `a` inside your loop, but not `count`, which you use in your `print` and `cv2.imwrite` commands. `count` remains `0` for every loop iteration, thus the stated behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start interpreting the code line-by-line:

- 1. **Variable initialization**

  - ```py
    import cv2

    cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    a=0
    count=0
    ```
- You load the opencv library and initialize the `cam` variable for webcam display. Then both `a` and `count` are intialized to 0. Now `count` variable is understandable, most probably `count` count the frames. What does `a` do?
- 2. **Display and save frames**

  - First-part
  - ```py
    for a in range(0, 5):
        ret,img=cam.read()
        cv2.imshow("Test",img)

        if not ret:
            break
    ```
  - variable `a` declared again so we don't need to intialize at the beginning. Then current web-frame is being fetched. The frame is given as an input to `imshow` without even the current frame returned or not. The correct logic should be:
  - ```py
    for a in range(5):
        ret,img=cam.read()

        if ret:
            cv2.imshow("Test",img)
    ```
  - Second-part
  - ```py
    k=cv2.waitKey(1)

    print("Image"+str(count)+"saved")
    file='C:/Users/User/Desktop/FACEREC/known_faces/img_test/ad2'+str(count)+'.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(file,img)
    a+=1
    ```
  - Now, the `k` variable is initialized as a key for quiting the program when a key is pressed. Say, when `q` is pressed program terminates.
  - ```py
    k=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if k == ord('q'):
         break
    ```
  - But if you break during the process, then you can't save the images. Therefore `break` should be at the end of the line.
  - For the rest of the code, you can use `a` as a counter. If you specify the start and end values. For each value `a` is increased by one. Then you can use it to discriminate the frames.

---

Code:

```py
# Load the library
import cv2

# Initialize webcam
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Save the frames
for a in range(0, 5):

    # Get current frame
    ret, img=cam.read()
   
    # If frame is returned
    if ret: 

        # Set the file-name
        file='C:/Users/User/Desktop/FACEREC/known_faces/img_test/ad2' + str(a) + '.jpg'
    
        # Write the frame
        cv2.imwrite(file, img)

        # Inform the user
        print("Image" + str(a) + "saved")

        # Display the frame
        cv2.imshow("Test", img)

        # If q is pressed quit
        k=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if k == ord('q'):
            break


# Release the object
cam.release()

# Close the window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad if I could help